# How open same activity with different extras from widget

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I have working with widgets which helpfull the user to show important data and open the application from widget.

My widget has 3 buttons and i need to open the app when user click on the different buttons.
i need to open same activity but with different data based on which button user clicked. I have passing different extra with intent

for example

Ist button i set user name as "Ranjith"

and for 2nd button i set user name as "Thomas"

and for 3rd button "Rixon"

But when the activity open it always shows Rixon the third one.

```
         logIntent= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            earnIntent=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            connectIntent=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            logIntent.putExtra("user_name", "Ranjith");
            connectIntent.putExtra("user_name", "Thomas");
            earnIntent.putExtra("user_name", "Rixon");
    }
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bottom_of_widget_log,createPendingIntent(context, 0, logIntent));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bottom_of_widget_earn, createPendingIntent(context, 1, earnIntent));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bottom_of_widget_connect, createPendingIntent(context, 2, connectIntent));
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context) ;
manager .updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

Comment: Post your code for the method `createPendingIntent()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the `android:launchMode` option in your Manifest,concerning the Activity.

As said in the  [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html),

> An activity with the "standard" or "singleTop" launch mode can be instantiated multiple times[....]
>   In contrast, "singleTask" and "singleInstance" activities can only begin a task. They are always at the root of the activity stack. Moreover, the device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one such task.